# python float '()' position

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

May I ask what is the difference between:

```
return float((Y2-Y1))/(X2-X1)
```

and:

```
return float((Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1))
```

My whole code is:

```
class Line(object):
    def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
        self.coor1 = coor1
        self.coor2 = coor2
    def slope(self):
        x1,y1 = self.coor1
        x2,y2 = self.coor2
        return float((Y2-Y1))/(X2-X1)

coor1 = (3,2)
coor2 = (8,10)
li = Line(coor1,coor2)
li.slope()
```

and the answer should be 1.6, but if the return part in my code is `return float((Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1))`, the answer will be 1.0.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? In this case, is there something preventing you from using Python 3?

Comment: but what is the difference @vaultah?

Comment: @vaultah Oh, yes, I had missed a closing parentheses...

Comment: Why make that so complicated with so much code? Wouldn't `float(8)/5` and `float(8/5)` show the exact same thing?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, integer division with '/' throws away remainders unless you import the 3.x feature.

```
>>> 8.0/5
1.6
>>> 8/5
1
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 8/5
1.6
```

Division with '//' always tosses remainders.

```
>>> 8//5
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 integer division:

```
>>> float(8) / 5
1.6
>>> float(8 / 5)
1.0
```

Fix with:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> float(8) / 5
1.6
>>> float(8 / 5)
1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2 a division is by default an integer one and it will always round to int

In your case when you do
`float(8/5)` you're casting to float the result of the division which is 1.6 and is rounded to 1.0

HOwever, by casting 8 to float with float(8) and then dividing by 5 you're forcing a float division which gives the correct result.
Same thing will happen with

```
8/float(5)
```